# How to make the user repository to use the extends property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I'm trying to make a generic repository, I'm using MongoDB for this, I tried to import it and use it in other classes but it didn't work.

So what I need is to make the repository class available through all the application, and every data that needs a db access should be able connect with the repository.

In this scenario

```
// userSchema.js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

// repository.js
class Repository {
    constructor(dbCollection) {
      this.dbCollection = dbCollection;
    }

    get(_id) {
        return this.dbCollection.findById({ _id });
    }
}

module.exports = Repository;

// user.repository.js
const Repository = require('./repository');

class UserRepository extends Repository {
  constructor(user) {
    super({
      dbCollection: user
    });
  }
}

module.exports = UserRepository;

// UserController.js

const UserRepository = require('./user.repository.js');

class UserController {
    async find(req, res) {
        const user = await UserRepository.get(req.params.id);
        return res.status(200).json(user);       
    }
}
module.exports = new UserController();

// mongo.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectionOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
};

class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.connect();
  }

  connect() {
    return mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, connectionOptions);
  }
}

module.exports = new Database();
```

I tried to do something like:

```
    const UserRepository = require('./user.repository.js');
    const schemaUser = require('./schemaUser');

    class UserController {
        async find(req, res) {
            const test = new UserRepository(schemaUser)
            const user = await test.get(req.params.id);
            return res.status(200).json(user);       
        }
    }
    module.exports = new UserController();
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What does it mean "didn't work"? Any errors or warnings? Unexpected results?

Comment: TypeError: this.dbCollection.find is not a function